# Delete a range based on a date criteria

Tags: vba

I have written the code below, which looks at the dates in column CD and if the date in any given cell is before the Todays Date (found in column H), the content in this cell is cleared. However, I would like the code to clear the content across multiple columns ("CD:CT") in the row(s) where a date before TodayDate is found.

Any suggestions on how to expand the Content Clearing?

```
Sub DeleteRange()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim numRowsWithVal As Long
    Dim myActiveCell As Range
    Dim todaysDate As Date

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    todaysDate = (Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value)

    numRowsWithVal = (Range("CD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    Set myActiveCell = ActiveSheet.Range("CD50")

    For i = 0 To numRowsWithVal

        Select Case True

            Case myActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value <= todaysDate

                myActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).ClearContents

        End Select

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code. Here is how it should look (comments in the code):

```
'ClearRange is better name for this subroutine, since it is not supposed to delete ranges but clear them instead.
Sub ClearRange()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim numRowsWithVal As Long
    Dim myActiveCell As Range
    'Dim todaysDate As Date


    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'You don't have to activate a worksheet to operate on its cells.
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate


    'No need for that. There is VBA built-in function that returns today date.
    'todaysDate = (Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value)

    numRowsWithVal = ws.Range("CD" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set myActiveCell = ActiveSheet.Range("CD50")

    For i = myActiveCell.Row To numRowsWithVal



        'This is not the proper usage of Select Case.
        'In Select Case you select between many available options. Here we can
        'only two options - the date is earlier or later than today.
        'In this case regular If statement is better choice.
'        Select Case True
'            Case myActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value <= todaysDate
'                myActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).ClearContents
'        End Select

        If ws.Range("CD" & i).Value <= VBA.Date Then
            Call ws.Range("CD" & i & ":CT" & i).ClearContents
        End If

    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer which works brilliantly and clearing up in my code!

Answer (score 0):

```
Intersect(Columns("CD:CT"), myActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).EntireRow).ClearContents
```